# Select checkboxes on the basis of previously selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The thing is, I want this checkbox to be selected on the basis of previously selected check box, for example, if I select first check box( which has some class) then it should only select that check box which has the class in the firstly selected checkbox using jquery.

Note: The check box are created dynamically and we can distinguish between then on the basis of class.

Thanks in advance.

```
<input class='class1' id='id1' value='id1Value' name='checkBoxName[]' type='checkbox'>CheckBox1<br>
<input class='class2' id='id2' value='id6Value' name='checkBoxName[]' type='checkbox'>CheckBox2<br>
<input class='class2' id='id3' value='id2Value' name='checkBoxName[]' type='checkbox'>CheckBox3<br>
<input class='class3' id='id4' value='id7Value' name='checkBoxName[]' type='checkbox'>CheckBox4<br>
<input class='class3' id='id5' value='id3Value' name='checkBoxName[]' type='checkbox'>CheckBox5<br>
<input class='class1' id='id6' value='id4Value' name='checkBoxName[]' type='checkbox'>CheckBox6<br>
```

This is it, when I select CheckBox1 checkbox, then it should only allow us to select the checkbox which has its class as class1 only, not other checkbox with class as class2 or class3 or any other.

Comment: You should post the code whatever you have done so far.

Comment: Its done, please look into it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't have more than one instance of the same `id`...

Comment: @msanford, changed the question, please check once.

Comment: But if I check first checkbox then 1st checkbox will be checked. Whats needs to be done. Its already there

Comment: Thats correct, i mean to say that, if we select first checkbox, then it should only allow us to check other checkbox which has same class name.

Comment: @SurajKandel, Check out my answer. That is your post's answer.

Comment: @SurajKandel, have you checked the code snippet ?

Comment: I have and created a fiddle and added the details in the comments too.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).find('input[name^="checkBoxName"]').click(function() {
       var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
       $(document).find('input[name^="checkBoxName"]').not('.'+class_name).attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer, I created fiddle and i dont think its working as i though.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/fenbgkp2/3/)

Please check into this.

The first check box is selected and it shouldnt select all the check box with the same class,  but it should allow us to select other check box with that classname.

Comment: Not exactly to disable other checkboxes, it shouldnt let us to check those other checkbox only.

Comment: yes, we can make it disable, but when we un check all check boxes then all  should be enable again

Comment: @SurajKandel, I have updated my answer. Check it now.

Comment: Awesome, thats is exactly as I thought.
Thanks

Comment: your welcome. Happy to help. Can I have an Up vote please ?

Comment: Sorry, i dont have enough reputation for doing up vote.